# InterpolatedUnivariateSpline and ax.fill_between yield unexpected result (filling wrong area) with low Y-values

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a function that is supposed to take some raw data, plot it onto a canvas and then fill the area between the baseline and a pre-defined peak, which works well for high Y-values but gives the inverse result when using low Y-values. My question is then two-fold:

1. Why does this occur?
2. What is a robust way to fix this issue (I tried multiplying all Y-values by 1E6 and, performing the InterpolatedUnivariateSpline fit and then dividing the returning fit by 1E6 again but there must be a better way to fix this).

Snippet:

```
X = [16.08278,16.090878,16.098978,16.107077,16.115177,16.123279,16.13138,16.139482,16.147586,16.155689,16.163793,16.171899,16.180004,16.18811,16.196218,16.204325,16.212433,16.220543,16.228652,16.236762,16.244874,16.252985,16.261097,16.269211,16.277324,16.285439,16.293554,16.30167,16.309786,16.317904,16.326021,16.334139,16.342259,16.350379,16.358499,16.366621,16.374742]
Y = [1.496555,1.766111,2.074339,2.426317,2.825952,3.274024,3.764088,4.288722,4.839724,5.406741,5.978055,6.536869,7.064041,7.540824,7.948076,8.267242,8.48543,8.596198,8.598762,8.492928,8.279867,7.962899,7.55062,7.059239,6.508092,5.91964,5.318298,4.7234,4.148229,3.602356,3.094568,2.635609,2.231337,1.882143,1.58295,1.328678,1.113859]
Y2 = [1496555,1766111,2074339,2426317,2825952,3274024,3764088,4288722,4839724,5406741,5978055,6536869,7064041,7540824,7948076,8267242,8485430,8596198,8598762,8492928,8279867,7962899,7550620,7059239,6508092,5919640,5318298,4723400,4148229,3602356,3094568,2635609,2231337,1882143,1582950,1328678,1113859]

# Toggle low vs high Y-values
#Y = Y2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(X, Y, 'b-')
plt.legend(['Raw Data'], loc='best')
plt.xlabel("Retention Time [m]")
plt.ylabel("Intensity [au]")
newTime = np.linspace(X[0], X[-1], len(X))
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(X, Y)
newIntensity = f(newTime)
ax.fill_between(X, newTime, newIntensity, alpha=0.5)
plt.show(fig)
```

This yields the following figures:

[image]
This is what I would expect (and occurs with high Y-values).

[image]
This occurs with low Y-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for answering my own question so fast but I noticed that I made a mistake when I initially implemented this that never came up before, as I always had high intensity data.

The `ax.fill_between` expects `x`, `y1` and `y2`, and with the high Y-value data it was starting the filled area not from 0 but from the X-value. This was not apparant because of the scale difference, and only became apparant after switching to low Y-values. Simply changing `ax.fill_between(X, newTime, newIntensity, alpha=0.5)` to `ax.fill_between(X, 0, newIntensity, alpha=0.5)` gives the expected result.